# pytest-asyncio tests not running async

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I'm trying to implement a simple async test suite. If my understanding is correct of async, the tests below should only take about 2 seconds to run. However, it's taking 6 seconds. What am I missing to make these test to run async ("at the same time")?

```
import logging
import pytest
import asyncio

MSG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(module)s->%(funcName)-15s |%(levelname)s| %(message)s"
MSG_DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
# Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
# Create Stream Handler
log_stream = logging.StreamHandler()
log_format = logging.Formatter(fmt=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=MSG_DATE_FORMAT)
log_stream.setFormatter(log_format)
log_stream.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
logger.addHandler(log_stream)

class TestMyStuff:

    @staticmethod
    async def foo(seconds):
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        return 1

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_1(self, event_loop):
        logger.info("start")
        assert await event_loop.create_task(self.foo(2)) == 1
        logger.info("end")

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_2(self, event_loop):
        logger.info("start")
        assert await event_loop.create_task(self.foo(2)) == 1
        logger.info("end")

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_3(self, event_loop):
        logger.info("start")
        # assert await event_loop.run_in_executor(None, self.foo) == 1
        assert await event_loop.create_task(self.foo(2)) == 1
        logger.info("end")
```

pytest extras:
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, aiohttp-1.0.4

[image]

Comment: The pytest-asyncio plugin doesn’t run all of your tests concurrently. They continue to run one at a time, but each marked test is scheduled with its own event loop.

Comment: You might be interested in the [pytest-xdist](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, pytest-xdist is what I’m trying to avoid. I’m wondering if I could use the pytest collection hooks to run the test functions “manually” in a single event loop.

Answer (score 1):

`pytest-asyncio` runs asynchronous tests serially. That plugin's goal is to make testing asynchronous code more convenient.

`pytest-asyncio-cooperative` on the other hand has the goal of running asyncio tests **concurrently** via cooperative multitasking (ie. all async coroutines sharing the same event loop and yielding to each other).

To try out `pytest-asyncio-cooperative` do the following:

1. Install the plugin

```
pip install pytest-asyncio-cooperative
```

2. Replace the `@pytest.mark.asyncio` marks with `@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative`
3. Remove all references to `event_loop`. `pytest-asyncio-cooperative` uses a single implicit event loop for asyncio interactions.
4. Run pytest with `pytest-asyncio` disabled. It is not compatible with `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`

```
pytest -p no:asyncio test_mytestfile.py
```

Here is the original code snippet with these modifications:

```py
import logging
import pytest
import asyncio

MSG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(module)s->%(funcName)-15s |%(levelname)s| %(message)s"
MSG_DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
# Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
# Create Stream Handler
log_stream = logging.StreamHandler()
log_format = logging.Formatter(fmt=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=MSG_DATE_FORMAT)
log_stream.setFormatter(log_format)
log_stream.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
logger.addHandler(log_stream)

class TestMyStuff:

    @staticmethod
    async def foo(seconds):
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        return 1

    @pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
    async def test_1(self):
        logger.info("start")
        assert await self.foo(2) == 1
        logger.info("end")

    @pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
    async def test_2(self):
        logger.info("start")
        assert await self.foo(2) == 1
        logger.info("end")

    @pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
    async def test_3(self):
        logger.info("start")
        # assert await event_loop.run_in_executor(None, self.foo) == 1
        assert await self.foo(2) == 1
        logger.info("end")
```

And here are the test results:

```
plugins: hypothesis-6.39.4, asyncio-cooperative-0.28.0, anyio-3.4.0, typeguard-2.12.1, Faker-8.1.0
collected 3 items                                                                  

test_mytestfile.py ...                                                       [100%]

================================ 3 passed in 2.18s =================================
```

Please checkout the README of `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`. Now that tests are run in a concurrent way you need to be wary of shared resources (eg. mocking)

Comment: This is plugin we ended up going with. Thanks!